# TWO_SWIPE_DOWN TAP unable to catch on Google Glass GDK (XE16)

Tags: android, google-glass, android-4.4-kitkat, gesture-recognition, gestures

In Google Glass XE16 [GestureDetector](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/GestureDetector) can detect several gestures like LONG_PRESS, SWIPE_DOWN, THREE_LONG_PRESS, TWO_SWIPE_DOWN , TWO_TAP & [SOME OTHER GESTURES](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/Gesture).

In glass TWO_SWIPE_DOWN is like shortcut option to cancel everything and go to black screen. After that black screen it comes **"ok glass"**.

But I need to override the TWO_SWIPE_DOWN TAP so that user can not go outside the application in this way. I want to show the user specific message in the time of tapping TWO_SWIPE_DOWN.

I have code following [GDK Touch Gestures](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch) like below :

```
    gestureDetector.setBaseListener(new GestureDetector.BaseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
            if (gesture == Gesture.TAP) {
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.TWO_TAP) {
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_RIGHT) {
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_LEFT) {
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.TWO_SWIPE_DOWN) {
                Log.i("Checking the TAPPING of TWO_SWIPE_DOWN", "Its working fine.");
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Above code able to catch every other tap without the TWO_SWIPE_DOWN TAP!

**So how I will be able to catch the TWO_SWIPE_DOWN TAP?**

Comment: It seems this problem still has not been fixed. I am unable to detect the TWO_SWIPE_DOWN gesture. Did you eventually find a fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is within a View/SurfaceView this is the implementation that Google provides

```
    /**
    * TextView that handles touchpad input (currently only TAP).
    */
    public class TouchpadHandlingTextView extends TextView
        implements OnAttachStateChangeListener{

    private final GestureDetector mTouchDetector;

    public TouchpadHandlingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mTouchDetector = createGestureDetector(context);
        // must set the view to be focusable
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }

    public TouchpadHandlingTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
        requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
    }

    /**
     * Pass a MotionEvent into the gesture detector
     */
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchGenericFocusedEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (isFocused()) {
            return mTouchDetector.onMotionEvent(event);
        }
        return super.dispatchGenericFocusedEvent(event);
    }

    /**
     * Create gesture detector that triggers onClickListener. Implement
     * onClickListener in your Activity and override
     * onClick() to handle the "tap" gesture.
     */
    private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
        GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(context);
        gd.setBaseListener(new GestureDetector.BaseListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
                if (gesture == Gesture.TAP) {
                    return performClick();
                }
                if(gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_DOWN){
                    //Do something instead of close app
                return true;
                }
            }
        });
        return gd;
    }
}
```

That will give you full control of your Views events.

Here is my reference from google.

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch

Comment: I want to add that for Glass the import statements are different than normal. Normally you can import `android.gesture.Gesture` and the like but for class you need to import whatever you need from `com.google.android.glass.touchpad` otherwise you'll get all sorts of vague errors thrown. Great thing Google doesn't list crap like that ANYWHERE on their touch docs.