# capturing TWO_SWIPE_DOWN on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I wonder how can one capture the two swipe down event on Google Glass, when using a GestureDetector. I seem to be able to capture all other events, but not TWO_SWIPE_DOWN. see the code below, it seems my onGesture() function is not even called in this case - e.g. the Log.e() message is not displayed in LogCat for TWO_SIPE_DOWN, but it is displayed for all other cases

```
private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context);
    //Create a base listener for generic gestures
    gestureDetector.setBaseListener( new GestureDetector.BaseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
            Log.e("Waveform", "gesture: " + gesture.toString());

            if (gesture == Gesture.TAP) {
                Log.e("WaveForm", "TAP");
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.TWO_TAP) {
                Log.e("WaveForm", "TWO_TAP");
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_RIGHT) {
                Log.e("WaveForm", "SWIPE_RIGHT");
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_LEFT) {
                Log.e("WaveForm", "SWIPE_LEFT");
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_UP) {
                Log.e("WaveForm", "SWIPE_UP");
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_DOWN) {
                Log.e("WaveForm", "SWIPE_DOWN");
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.TWO_SWIPE_DOWN) {
                Log.e("WaveForm", "TWO_SWIPE_DOWN");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    gestureDetector.setFingerListener(new GestureDetector.FingerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFingerCountChanged(int previousCount, int currentCount) {
          // do something on finger count changes
        }
    });
    gestureDetector.setScrollListener(new GestureDetector.ScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(float displacement, float delta, float velocity) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return gestureDetector;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218457/two-swipe-down-tap-unable-to-catch-on-google-glass-gdk-xe16

Comment: I want to add that for Glass the import statements are different than normal. Normally you can import `android.gesture.Gesture` and the like but for class you need to import whatever you need from `com.google.android.glass.touchpad` otherwise you'll get all sorts of vague errors thrown. Great thing Google doesn't list crap like that ANYWHERE on their touch docs.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue. I am unable to detect the TWO_SWIPE_DOWN gesture. Is there a solution for this?